# how do I build a protocol header and body over a tcp socket in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a tacacs+ client,

I'm trying to write a simple packet to send to the server,
I checked [the RFC page](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-grant-tacacs-02) and I saw the protocol needs to get this header in every packet:

```
    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
    |major  | minor  |                |                |                |
    |version| version|      type      |     seq_no     |   flags        |
    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
    |                                                                   |
    |                            session_id                             |
    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
    |                                                                   |
    |                              length                               |
    +----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

now I'm pretty new with this,
and I'm not sure how do I build this header,
is creating a buffer like this good enough?:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%x%x%x%x%x",version,version,type,seq,flags,session_id,length);
```

and then take this buffer and attach it the body in the same way and send:

```
send(socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
```

or is there another way of doing this whole packet building?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have doesn't produce the right output at all!

The following is portable:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

uint8_t* pack_uint8(uint8_t* dest, uint8_t src) {
   *(dest++) = src;
   return dest;
}

uint8_t* pack_uint32be(uint8_t* dest, uint32_t src) {
   *(dest++) = src >> 24;
   *(dest++) = (src >> 16) & 0xFF;
   *(dest++) = (src >> 8) & 0xFF;
   *(dest++) = src & 0xFF;
   return dest;
}

uint8_t* build_packet(
   uint8_t maj_version,
   uint8_t min_version,
   uint8_t type,
   uint8_t seq,
   uint8_t flags,
   uint32_t session_id,
   uint32_t body_length,
   const uint8_t* body
) {
   uint8_t* packet = malloc(12 + body_length);
   uint8_t* p = packet;
   p = pack_uint8(p, ( maj_version << 4 ) | min_version);
   p = pack_uint8(p, type);
   p = pack_uint8(p, seq);
   p = pack_uint8(p, flags);
   p = pack_uint32be(p, session_id);
   p = pack_uint32be(p, body_length);
   memcpy(p, body, body_length);
   return packet;
}
```

Comment: wow thank you very much!
i understand things much better now!
now all i have to do is attach the body same way you did the header right?

Comment: Since a streaming protocol (TCP) is used, the header and body can be output using separate `send`/`write` calls. But I've modified my answer to build the whole packet at once. Don't forget to `free` it!

Comment: ohh i didn't know i can do 2 **sends** functions to send 1 packet thanks for the information :)