# Type Safe Vs Loosely typed - GO Vs C

Tags: c, go, casting

In C, following is the sniffer code,

```
void Handle_IP(char *buf)
{
    struct iphdr *ip_hdr; // declaring pointer of type ip header 

    struct in_addr in; // declaring a structure which holds ip address 

    FILE *fp;
    int ctl, len;

    /* In the following statement we're adjusting the offset so that
       ip pointer can point to correct location */

    ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)(buf + 14);
    ....
}
```

---

where line,

`ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)(buf + 14)` has `char *` that is type casted to `struct iphdr *`.

GO being a type safe language, does not allow such type casting. Go has no `void *` except `interface` that follows structural typing

How to approach such code in GO?

Comment: @soundslikeodd Can you edit again? Sorry

Comment: actually that might not be safe in C either ...

Comment: The C code does different things on different compilers and machines because of differences in alignment restrictions, alignment, padding, and endianness. It can even cause a segfault. The safe, portable thing to do is to extract a field at a time, the reverse of what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39132179/589924) does.

Comment: @ikegami we have assembly code embedded in C application. How do u  embed assembly code in GO?

Comment: 1) Don't post new questions in the comments. If you have a new question, post it as a Question. Though stop asking how to translate things, and start asking how to do the things the code you want translated does. 2) I don't know GO

Comment: You may find this package useful: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/ipv4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Foreword:** Even though what you want is possible, try to avoid using package `unsafe` as much as possible. This is not a "go to first" solution but rather think of it as a last resort (or something that comes after that).

---

Go does give you support for this in package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/).

Even the spec has a dedicated section for it. [Spec: Package `unsafe`:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe)

> The built-in package `unsafe`, known to the compiler, provides facilities for low-level programming including operations that violate the type system. A package using `unsafe` must be vetted manually for type safety and may not be portable.

The package was intentionally named `unsafe`, giving you the proper prior-warning that if something goes wrong, don't blame the compiler or the language.

What you need is the [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) type. `Pointer` is a special [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) that may not be [dereferenced](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), but any pointer type can be converted to `Pointer`, and `Pointer` can be converted to any (other) pointer type. So this is your "gateway" between different types.

For example, if you have a value of type `float64` (which is 8 bytes in memory), you can interpret those 8 bytes as an `int64` (which is also 8 bytes in memory) like this:

```
var f float64 = 1
var i int64

ip := (*int64)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
i = *ip

fmt.Println(i)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IicOAa8kUA)):

```
4607182418800017408
```

The key is this line:

```
(*int64)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
```

It means take the address of `f` (which will be of type `*float64`), convert it to `unsafe.Pointer` (any pointer type can be converted to `Pointer`), then convert this `unsafe.Pointer` value to another pointer type `*int64`. If we dereference this pointer, we get a value of type `int64`.

In your example you want to "place" a variable on an address with an offset applied. Go does not have pointer arithmetic. You can get around this in 2 ways:

1. use [`uintptr`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#uintptr) which may hold an address, but you can treat it as an `int` and add values to it
2. or use a pointer to a "buffer" type, e.g. `*[1<<31]byte`; you may convert the address to this pointer, and you can apply the offset by indexing the buffer at the given offset, and take the address of that element, e.g. `&buf[14]`

Method #1 could look likes this:

```
type X [16]byte
var x = X{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

xx := (uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&x[0])) + 14 // APPLY OFFSET

var x2 X = *(*X)(unsafe.Pointer(xx))
fmt.Println(x2[0], x2[1])
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0DbHhSh9WT)):

```
14 15
```

Method #2 could look like this:

```
type X [16]byte
var x = X{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}

xx := (*X)(unsafe.Pointer(&x[0]))
xx = (*X)(unsafe.Pointer(&xx[14])) // APPLY OFFSET

var x2 X = *(*X)(unsafe.Pointer(xx))
fmt.Println(x2[0], x2[1])
```

Output is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JFxFdXsTMm).

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at this from a different angle: what does typecasting do in C?

Well, in some sense, it doesn't do anything! It just takes some bit pattern at some point in memory, and blindly assumes that this particular bit pattern actually represents a value of some type. But there's no validation of this, no sort of parsing. And that's the problem.

But, I already used the word that is the solution to our problem above: parsing. Instead of just blindly assuming that some random bit pattern in memory is the same bit pattern that the C compiler would generate for a value of some type, we actually *look at the bit pattern*, check whether it conforms to the rules of how bit patterns for that datatype are constructed, and deconstruct the bit patterns into its constituent parts according to those rules.

In other words: we write a parser.

Note that this isn't specific to Go. It is a good idea even in C. In fact, the code you posted is broken in at least three, maybe four different ways:

- platforms where a `char` is not 8 bits wide
- alignment
- padding
- endianness

AFAIK, there are already existing IP, UDP, and TCP parsers written in Go out there, that you can either use or learn from. Also, the current system from Alan Kay's Viewpoints Research Institute has a really cool TCP/IP stack written in just 120 lines or so, which is very easy to read. (In fact, the source code for the parser actually just consists of ASCII diagrams cut&pasted from the RFCs.)